# Deleting specific messages that was sent by the bot and sent by the user. Discord.py rewrite

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm having a lot of trouble with discord.py rewrite and its migration. I looked at the migrating to v1.0 site and it said to put in message.delete() and so I did but I realised that wasn't working so I put in ctx aswell. But that put it to an error. There are two commands with this error at the moment.

I have already tried putting the message into a variable.

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
    message = ctx.message
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    messages = []
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount+1))
    mymessage = await channel.send('Messages deleted')
    await ctx.message.delete(mymessage)

@client.command()
async def verify(ctx, *, arg):
    print(ctx.message.channel.id)
    print(ctx.message.author)
    if ctx.channel.id == 521645091098722305:
        role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name=arg)
        await ctx.message.author.add_roles(role)
        mymessage = await ctx.send('Done! Welcome!')
        await ctx.message.delete(mymessage)
        await ctx.message.delete(ctx.message)
```

I expected the output to delete the message. For the clear one it deletes it and then gives it back. for the verify one it just keeps it as the same and shows the error:
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Also my role giving verify sometimes goes 3 times. I have went into task manager and killed all of the python too but it still did that. Once when I was clearing it said Done! Welcome as well. If you can answer this question as well, I would be pleased! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[`Message.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete) doesn't take any arguments.  It's a method that you call on the message you want to delete.  Change

```
await ctx.message.delete(mymessage)
await ctx.message.delete(ctx.message)
```

to

```
await mymessage.delete()
await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: thank you very much, but I don't know why but the command plays more than once. (the verify one)

Comment: actually nvm, now it works. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I didn't mention this before in the problem but how do you get a role into a variable in rewrite?

Comment: `await ctx.message.author.add_roles(ctx.guild.get_role(537601033422241821))`
this is what I got so far but it doesn't work:

`File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 532, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct id?  You can also use `discord.utils.get` to get it by name: `get(ctx.guild.roles, name="my_role")`

Comment: This time it says MISSING PERMISSIONS even though I gave all perms to the bot.

Comment: Can you either ask a new question with all the info or edit the new error into your original question?  You may be running into a role hierarchy issue, where you can't manipulate a role that is higher in the hierarchy than your own highest role.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def delete(ctx, arg):
    arg1 = int(arg) + 1
    await client.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=arg1)
```

!delete 10 - delete the last 10 posts

Comment: I am in rewrite, so that doesn't work for me. sorry. Don't worry I fixed it anyways :) Thanks for the help.